# T-SQL get sub-string up to but not including first single forward slash

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Using T-SQL, I would like to retrieve the sub-string up to but not including the first single forward-slash. For example:

"https://domain/xyz/" should become "https://domain"

Would appreciate some guidance on how to accomplish this.

Comment: you should locate known strings:
so locate the location of "https://" and then locate the first occurrence of "/" after that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution will handle one or more forward slashes after and and any protocol prefix (e.g. http, https, ftp, etc).

```
declare @str varchar(100) = 'https://domain/xyz/';
select substring(@str, 1, charindex('/',@str,(charindex('://',@str))+3)-1);
```

If the possibility exists that there won't be a forward slash after the protocol (e.g. https://domain) then you could use the solution below. What I put together is some easily consumable sample data.

```
declare @table table (s varchar(100));
insert @table values 
('https://domain1/blahblah//'),
('http://domain2/fff/ggg/hhh'),
('https://domainX/ppp/20%xx/'),
('ftp://ftpserver6/zzzzz');

select isnull(substring(s,1,nullif(charindex('/',s,(charindex('://',s))+3),0)-1),s)
from @table t;
```

**Returns**

```
https://domain1
http://domain2
https://domainX
ftp://ftpserver6
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this will work:

```
select left(str, patindex('%[^/]/[^/]%', str) )
```

If the string might end with the first hyphen, you can always do:

```
select left(str, patindex('%[^/]/[^/]%', str + 'x') )
```

Comment: This works, except if the string happens to be just `https://domain/` with nothing behind it. May or may not be relevant for OP.

Comment: Nice solution. Thank you.